# Locking columns in a ExtJS 4 TreePanel?

Tags: extjs4

Does anyone know how to enable locking on a TreePanel column in ExtJS 4.1.1?

Comment: What do you mean by locking, stopping user interaction?

Comment: No. Locked columns stay locked on the left side and don't scroll with the rest of the columns horizontally. This is an option, which works on a GridPanel, and in 4.1.0 it worked on a TreePanel with a workaround, but now I can't get it to work anymore.

Comment: have you tried doing any css workarounds with "overflow-x" ?

Answer (score 0):

for specific columns to be locked, you can add locked: true in the column config, for the entire grid use enableLocking: true in the grid config